# Reference a cell's content to act as a sheet name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to be able to reference the contents of a cell as a sheet name.

The content of A2 is "32033", which is also the name of a different sheet in the workbook. In B2, I'm trying to identify the average of a range that sheet.

```
=AVERAGE('32033'!B2:B)
```

I'm trying to replace the '32033' with a formula referencing A2.

Comment: Use the `INDIRECT` function. For example, your formula would be `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(A2&"!B2:B"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use **`INDIRECT`** formula to reference the sheet name from a cell:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(A2&"!B2:B"))
```